# Menu Item Check and Uncheck

Tags: wpf, menu, checked, unchecked

I want the menu work like this: when I click on any of the items in the `Menu`, it gets checked. Now when I select another item from the same `Menu`, the previously selected item becomes unchecked and the newly selected item appears as checked.

```
<DockPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="Onfilter_Click" />
    </Style>
</DockPanel.Resources>

<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
    <MenuItem x:Name="filtermenu" Header="_FilterType" BorderBrush="White" >
        <MenuItem Header="ShowAll" IsChecked="True" />
        <MenuItem Header="FirstPage" />
        <MenuItem Header="Secondpage"  InputGestureText="Alt+F3" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

In the code above, I have handled how to **Check and Uncheck** the items. If I execute the below method, everything gets **unchecked**.

And also if I press <kbd>Alt+F3</kbd>, the **Secondpage** MenuItem has to be handled,
even though if it gets handled, the **Onfilter_Click** method will get called. How can I achieve this?

```
Private Sub Onfilter_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim b As MenuItem = TryCast(sender, MenuItem)

        If Not obj Is Nothing Then

            For i As Integer = 0 To filtermenu.Items.Count - 1

                Dim mni As System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem = DirectCast(filtermenu.Items(i), System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem)
                Dim s As String = mni.Header

                If Not s = b.Header Then
                    If mni.IsChecked Then
                        mni.IsChecked = False
                    End If
                Else
                    If Not mni.IsChecked Then
                        mni.IsChecked = True
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            ' b.IsChecked = True
            obj.FilterImages(b.Header)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: So you want multiple items that you click to be `checked`?

Comment: @WPF-it ,No,not like that, If i `Checked` one item ,all other items must be `Unchecked`

Comment: Then what is happening in your case?

Comment: If i execute the above code `ShowAll` Menuitem will be **Checked** by default, now when i click `Firstpage`, `ShowAll` menuitem gets **Unchecked**,this is correct, but `FirstPage` **MenuItem** is not getting Checked. I couldn figure out the solution